# Creating Subtables in Piwik

Tags: plugins, matomo

I am new to piwik.Please help me in my issue.

Issue: I have to create 4 levesl of subtables.Currently I can able to create upto 2nd level,I mean table with one subtable per row.
Basically If I click on a table row I shoud get the subtable.If I click on subtable row again it should show inner subtable.
I need to create Table->subtable->subtable->subtable.

My code  :

```
function getpageViewsLevel1($idSite, $date, $period)
        {

         $query = "select * from....";

                $result = Piwik_FetchAll($query, array($idSite, $dateStart, $dateEnd));

                // convert this array to a DataTable object
                $dataTable = new Piwik_DataTable();

                //Add subtable to each result
                foreach ($result as $arr){
                        $piwik_row = new Piwik_DataTable_Row;
                        $piwik_row->setColumns($arr);
                        $subDataTable = new Piwik_DataTable();
                        $piwik_row->addSubTable($subDataTable);
                        $dataTable->addRow($piwik_row);
                }
                return $dataTable;
        }

function getpageViewsLevel2($idSite, $date, $period, $idSubtable)
        {

                // Find selected parent row and retrieve data

                $dataTable_old = $this->getpageViewsLevel1($idSite, $date, $period);
                $row_old = new Piwik_DataTable_Row;
                $row_old=$dataTable_old->getRowFromIdSubDataTable($idSubtable+1);

                $tmp=$row_old->getColumns();
                //Using $actionName in DB Query
                $actionName=$tmp['pageTitle'].'%';

                //db query
                $query = "select * ....";

                $result = Piwik_FetchAll($query, array($idSite, $dateStart, $dateEnd, $actionName));

                // convert this array to a DataTable object
                //$dataTable = new Piwik_DataTable();
                foreach ($result as $arr){
                        $piwik_row = new Piwik_DataTable_Row;
                        $piwik_row->setColumns($arr);
                    $subDataTable = new Piwik_DataTable();
                        $piwik_row->addSubTable($subDataTable);
                        $dataTable->addRow($piwik_row);
                }
                return $dataTable;
        }
```

---

### Till here works fine.For the 3rd level,I am not able to apply the same logic as I dont have the 2ng level table ID.

```
function getpageViewsLevel3($idSite, $date, $period, $idSubtable)
        {

                // Find selected parent row and retrieve data

                $dataTable_old = $this->getpageViewsLevel2($idSite, $date, $period, ___???????????????);
```

---

Please help me how can I proceed with this issue.Please let me know is there any other solution to do this.
Though if I pass some number like '1' for testing,

```
$dataTable_old = $this->getpageViewsLevel2($idSite, $date, $period, 1);----->this is not working.
```

I need to use parent row info in my DB query.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It helps to (1) Focus Your Title -- Write a SHORT summary of what you need.   (2) Read the right side of the page and edit your question carefully so it looks good.  (3) Focus your question onto exactly what you need.  (4) Summarize where possible.

Comment: I guarantee you that this website is *not* a mailing address for anything, let along the support address for piwik

Comment: did you find the solution? I am also stuck with 3 level subtables...
if you found the solution please share. thank you